# Align 2 span one left and the other right inside a div

Tags: html, css, positioning

Could anybody write the CSS fragment to do this?

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="left">Left</span><span class="right">Right</span>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS for `.container`:

```
.container {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

Notice the position is absolute because it is "absolute positionated" on its containing element.

I've alredy tried `float:left`/`float:right` on the two nested elements but nothing happens.

Answer (score 6):

Set the elements to block, set a width and float them.

```
.left{
  display: block;
  float:left;
  width: 100px;
}

.right{
  display: block;
  float:right;
  width: 100px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/LML2e/

Comment: this isn't the solution and `float` already causes a `display: block;`, which is just fine in this case.

Comment: This is great. One note: the width can also be a percentage, which is cool.

Answer (score 2):

`float: left` and `float: right` will work perfectly when you set a (relative or absolute) width for your `.container` div

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RBFJ5/)

```
.container {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    width: 200px; //either absolute width
    width: 100%;  // or relative width
}
```

*Side note:* If you set the `.container` to `width: 100%` you will get ugly scroll bars due to the `margin`. Just use the `margin` in the `.left` and `.right` classes. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RBFJ5/1/).

Comment: Ok, I just forgot to set widht:100%; to the container. Thanks a lot. Just une more thing: let's suppose to set .left's font size to 200%, how can I get to have .left and .right aligned at the bottom of the .container element?

Comment: This isn't possible with `float`. Maybe you should use `display: inline-block` instead. http://jsfiddle.net/RBFJ5/7/ Other option would be to use a table

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a width in order to use `float`. If you want a width of 100% you can set `.container { width: 100%; }` or improve your code into something like:

```css
.container {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:5px;
    left:5px;
    right:5px;
}
```